# Installing Hadoop, Zookeeper, AccumuLo on Mac

Tags: macos

### EDIT

JavaJDK 1.6
Hadoop
ZooKeeper
AccumuLo

Hadoop is starting up and seems to be running fine.  Tested the NameNode and JobTracker and they both can be seen in the localhost html page.

ZooKeeper server starts up fine, but I get the error in the Client shell.

You can see the errors from ZooKeeper and AccumuLo below.

### ORIGINAL

I am attempting to install these technologies on a OS X loaded with Mountain Lion for testing purposes.  The setup is a single-node setup using 'localhost'.

I am running into a few issues...

1) running sudo zkCli -> ls / throws an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1468)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1496)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:725)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:593)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:365)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:323)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:282)
```

2) I attempt to run bin/accumulo init and receive this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/start/Platform
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.start.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/start/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.accumulo.start.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

It seems that there is something wrong with my class but I am not sure what I need to do.

Here is the summary of the AccumuLo compile:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Project ........................... SUCCESS [17.267s]
[INFO] Trace ............................................. SUCCESS [7.819s]
[INFO] Fate .............................................. SUCCESS [2.638s]
[INFO] Start ............................................. SUCCESS [49.560s]
[INFO] Core .............................................. SUCCESS [2:57.195s]
[INFO] Server ............................................ SUCCESS [23.385s]
[INFO] Examples .......................................... SUCCESS [0.321s]
[INFO] Simple Examples ................................... SUCCESS [19.038s]
[INFO] MiniCluster ....................................... SUCCESS [38.770s]
[INFO] Accumulo Maven Plugin ............................. SUCCESS [20.568s]
[INFO] Testing ........................................... SUCCESS [2:55.802s]
[INFO] Proxy ............................................. SUCCESS [1:36.702s]
[INFO] Assemblies ........................................ SUCCESS [17.033s]
[INFO] Documentation ..................................... SUCCESS [0.282s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10:49.977s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 29 15:05:17 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/83M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The easiest way I know of for testing purposes is to grab the [Hortonworks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/) image for the virtual machine of your choice and run it that way.  It won't give you experience configuring a cluster from scratch, but if you want to test it out from a user perspective is a great start.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. We have a guide on how to ask - have a look at it and see if you could add an edit to list either what step you've taken to try to solve it (and why it didn't work) or at least let us know exactly the version of java you have installed `java -version` or exactly what package you installed your third party software. The chance of someone helping goes up if you can narrow down the options a bit.

Comment: @AlanShutko - you should put that in as a real answer. Offloading all the patching, dependancies, etc... is a valid answer for someone just getting started with testing. Even if this OP really needs to figure out the basic install steps, it will help others in all likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of to start with testing is to grab the [Hortonworks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/) VM image.  It provides a CentOS Linux base and comes with Hadoop and Zookeeper.  They provide VMs for VMWare and VirtualBox (which is free) that will run on the Mac, and I've used it with Parallels.  (I took the VMWare VM and converted it with the [VMWare OVF Tool](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/ovf/) from an OVF to a vmware image which Parallels could convert.)

It does not contain Accumulo, but it gives you a working foundation that might make it easier to install stuff.